# Most long series of element in array

Tags: c, arrays, function, max, definition

I've prepared a code that should found the longer series of elements in growing order .for example ,in arrays exists following elements : 1 2 3 4 5 2 7 6 7 9,output will 5 (the series from 1 to 5) ,function will return integer tempcount that include numbers of element and print it.but get an error ,the function
isn't working:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int find_maximum(int[], int);

 int main() {
 int c, array[100], size, location, maximum,found;


   scanf_s("%d", &size);



 for (c = 0; c < size; c++)
scanf_s("%d", &array[c]);

 location = find_maximum(array, size);
  maximum  = found;


  printf("Maximum elements = %d ",  maximum);
   return 0;
}

 int find_maximum(int a[], int n) {
int c, index = 0,count =1,tempCount=1;

for (c = 1; c < n; c++)
if (a[c] > a[index])

   count +=1;
else
{
    if (count > tempCount)
    {
        tempCount=count;
    }
}

return tempCount;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The variables `maximum` and `found` are not initialized and are used nowhere except this statement that does not make sense

```
maximum  = found;
```

You are storing the length of the maximum subsequence in the variable `location`

```
location = find_maximum(array, size);
```

It is the variable value which you need to output.

The function `find_maximum` also does not make sense. For example you are comparing elements of the array with the same element at position 0.

```
int c, index = 0,count =1,tempCount=1;
       ^^^^^^^^^
for (c = 1; c < n; c++)
if (a[c] > a[index])

   count +=1;
   //…
```

The function can be declared and implemented as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t max_ascending_seq( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t max_n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; )
    {
        size_t current_n = 1;

        while ( ++i < n && a[i-1] < a[i] ) ++current_n;

        if ( max_n < current_n ) max_n = current_n;
    }

    return max_n;
}


int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 6, 7, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t max_n = max_ascending_seq( a, N );

    printf( "%zu\n", max_n );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5
```

A more generic function can be written the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t max_ascending_seq( const int a[], size_t n, int predicate( int, int ) )
{
    size_t max_n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; )
    {
        size_t current_n = 1;

        while ( ++i < n && predicate( a[i-1], a[i] ) ) ++current_n;

        if ( max_n < current_n ) max_n = current_n;
    }

    return max_n;
}


int less_than( int x, int y )
{
    return x < y;
}

int greater_than( int x, int y )
{
    return y < x; 
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 6, 7, 9 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t max_n = max_ascending_seq( a, N, less_than );

    printf( "%zu\n", max_n );

    max_n = max_ascending_seq( a, N, greater_than );

    printf( "%zu\n", max_n );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5
2
```

Comment: when i try to run get an error:Error 1error LNK1168:

Comment: @AlexanderBazikalo Please try to copy and paste the program as is without errors.

Comment: is it correct to do this way?size_t max_ascending_seq( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    size_t max_n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; )
    {
        size_t current_n = 1;

        while ( ++i < n && a[i-1] < a[i] ) ++current_n;

        if ( max_n < current_n ) max_n = current_n;
    }

    return max_n;
}


int main(void) 
{
    int c, array[100];
    const size_t N ; 


   scanf("%d", &N);


  for (c = 0; c < N; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);

    size_t max_n = max_ascending_seq( a, N );

    printf( "%zu\n", max_n );

    return 0;
}

Comment: @AlexanderBazikalo No it is not correct. You are declaring the variable N as a constant. You may not change it. Write size_t n; scanf( "%zu", &n );  for ( size_t i = 0 i  < n; i++ ) scanf( "%d", &array[i] ); size_t max_n = max_ascending_seq( array, n );

Comment: Warning 1 warning C4101: 'c' : unreferenced local variable c:\users\alexander.ba\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\longarray.c\longarray\longarray.cpp 26 1 LongArray

Comment: @AlexanderBazikalo Remove the variable if it is not used.